# Define custom array type in Java

Tags: java, syntax, types, typedef

Here are type definitions from Delphi:

```pascal
type
  MD5Count = array [0 .. 1] of DWORD;
  MD5State = array [0 .. 3] of DWORD;
```

could the same typedefs be done in Java?

For reference:
The example above defines two custom data types. One of them is a two-elements array of Int32, other is a four-elements array of Int32.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in Java. I think you would use a class encapsulating that, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no typedefs in java. Arrays are either of one of the primitive types, or some class that will just compile away to object references.

Comment: Any example? I am not familiar to Java.

Comment: @Paul He is saying that you would define a `DWORD[]` with his second point, which is actually unrelated to his first point, i.e. Java does not have `typedef`.

Comment: @Paul the java type int is 32 bits (always). So the closest thing to your MD5Count type would be a class with a single member which is an array of two elements, for example. Java pretty much forces you to abandon non object approaches to data.